Filling NaNs by mode
I have data with a lot of NaNs:
train_feat["portarbre"].value_counts(dropna=False)
portarbre
NaN             12958
Libre            6070
Semi-libre       4449
Architecturé      316
Pyramidale          7
Pleureur            4
Name: count, dtype: int64

And a column with no NaNs:
data["adr_secteur"].value_counts(dropna=False)
adr_secteur
6        6958
5        6728
2        6066
3        4249
4        4128
1        3376
38309     180
38151      92
38421      68
38249      41
38158       9
Name: count, dtype: int64

I have other columns also with less NaNs but this one will illustrate the issue. Even though there is a lot of NaNs that the easiest decision would be to just drop the column, filling those 12k of null values can be at least illustrative as an exercise. So I decided to fill the null values with the mode conditioned on the sous_categorie column like the following:
mode_sect_df = train_feat.groupby("portarbre")["adr_secteur"].agg(lambda x: x.mode().max()).reset_index()
mode_sect_df.columns = ["portarbre", "mode_sect"]

for index, row in mode_sect_df.iterrows():

    haut_value = row["portarbre"]
    mode_sect = row["mode_sect"]
    train_feat.loc[train_feat["adr_secteur"] == mode_sect, "portarbre"] = \
        train_feat.loc[train_feat["adr_secteur"] == mode_sect,"portarbre"].fillna(value=haut_value)

That is, I am filling the null values in the portarbre column by taking the mode corresponding to the adr_secteur column:
train_feat.pivot_table(index='adr_secteur', columns='portarbre', aggfunc='size')

portarbre   Architecturé    Libre   Pleureur    Pyramidale  Semi-libre
adr_secteur                  
1           27.0            385.0   NaN          1.0         842.0
2           2691.0          1094.0  1.0          3.0         917.0 
3           20.0            622.0   NaN          NaN         655.0
4           61.0            653.0   NaN          NaN         534.0
5           79.0            1627.0  3120.0       NaN         358.0
6           17.0            4069.0  1.0          3.0         1079.0
38151       NaN             3.0     NaN          NaN         57.0
38158       NaN             NaN     NaN          NaN         7.0

The problem is, after running the code I end with:
 train_feat["portarbre"].value_counts(dropna=False)
 
 portarbre
 Libre           8453
 NaN             4878
 Semi-libre      4449
 Pleureur        3122
 Architecturé    2895
 Pyramidale         7
 Name: count, dtype: int64

I see two problems here (maybe you will see many others):
1- First is the obvious one: not all null values are being filled. In the first count there were 12958 nulls in the "portarbre" column. In the second, after the imputation, there are 4878. I don't see the error in the code. There is no nulls in the column adr_secteur', the one I am using as support to fill the nulls in the adr_secteur`.
2- The second is that more than one category can have the same mode:
mode_stade_dev = train_feat.groupby("hauteurarbre")["stadededeveloppement"].agg(lambda x: x.mode().max()).reset_index()
mode_stade_dev.columns = ["hauteurarbre", "mode_stade"]

    hauteurarbre    mode_stade
0   Moins de 10 m   Arbre adulte
1   Plus de 20 m    Arbre adulte
2   de 10 m à 20 m  Arbre adulte

That is, in the first interaction in the for loop, when selecting Arbre adulte to fill the values, it will fill all nan values with Moins de 10 m and then there will be no more null values to be filled for the other modes. How can I improve this? I don't want to just select the mode of the column to fill all the null values in that column. Maybe this will work for that specific column, but I have others in the dataset that this won't be a good idea (for example, the category of a tree and the stage of its development has different modes depending on the category, but some of them will repeat raising this same issue that I am discussing here).

what is the shape of mode_sect_df, do you have all the distinct values from adr_secteur in it? what does print(set( data["adr_secteur"])-set(mode_sect_df['mode_sect'])) return? My guess is because you have only 5 distinct values (except nan) in portarbre then you will get only 5 modes aka 5 values from adr_secteur that will be used to fill the nan in your loop while you have 11 distincts. So your loop does not work for all distincts values from adr_secteur hence you keep nan in the other column

I think the columns in the groupby should be inversed: you want train_feat.groupby("adr_secteur")["portarbre"].agg(lambda x: x.mode().max()).reset_index() then adapt the column's name. it should also solve your second question as mode_stade will then have only unique values.

You should make the portarbre<->adr_secteur grouped dataframe reversed:
mode_sect_df = train_feat.dropna(
    subset=["portarbre"]  # if NA is most popular for some values
).groupby("adr_secteur")["portarbre"].agg(
    lambda x: x.mode().max()
)
train_feat.fillna(
    {"portarbre": train_feat["adr_secteur"].map(mode_sect_df)},
     inline=True
)


And then in each row where portarbre is missed, you fill it with the most popular value for rows with that adr_secteur value.
To understand why it is so, imagine you have a data frame where you have the sex and the height of a person, and there are 100 rows for men and 10000 for women, and some heights are missed.  You will fill in missed height data by average height for each sex, not by popular sex for each height (for all heights, "woman" will be the most popular sex due to extreme data imbalance).
Also, if you want to learn more about this, you can read about "missing not at random" (MNAR). It will help you decide if this method makes sense for your data.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK493614/

Thank you very much for your time and for that answer. I already tested here and it fixed the problems. Thanks :)
